# Integrate nowpayments gateway to add action in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, payment, elementor, add-action

I have problem integraring the api of nowpayments gateway to add_action function in functions.php

I have an elementor form. The data users enter added to db. I have added a code to functions.php. the data added to database after I press the button at the end of the form. Now I want to integrate the payment gateway to the existing code. The data  added to database without referring to payment gateway after adding the gateway code to the current code. Does anyone have the same experience.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.